# Нужно реализовать библиотеку функций для построителя строк

Tags: c, строки, указатели, память, char

Нужно реализовать библиотеку функций для построителя строк, позволяющую «собирать строку» по частям (в динамической памяти, из других строк и символов, соединяя их последовательно). Компилятор выдает ошибку(в функции char*gluestr невозможно преобразовать тип void в char), помогите пожалуйста.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char*topstr(char*str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);                      
    char*top =(char*) malloc(len + 1);

    if (!top) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed: insufficient memory!\n");
        return NULL;
    }
        
    return top;
}
 
 char*gluestr(char*top, char*anystr)
 {
    size_t len1 = strlen(top);
    size_t len2 = strlen(anystr);
    topstr(top);
    top=realloc(top, sizeof(char)*(len1+len2+1));
    
    if (!top) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed: insufficient memory!\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    strcat(top, anystr);
    
    return top;
 }
 
 int main()
 {
    char str1[20];
    char str2[20];
    puts("Type a string");
    fgets(str1,sizeof(str1),stdin);
    fgets(str2,sizeof(str2),stdin);
    
    gluestr(str1,str2);
    puts(str1);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Может сразу взять и использовать [asprintf()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ошибки

0. Не компилируется потому что вы, видимо, компилируете код C++ компилятором. Компилятор C не будет выдавать эту ошибку. В C++ `void *` не приводится автоматически к `char *`, а в C приводится.
1. `topstr` выделяет память и забывает скопировать туда строку.
2. `gluestr` вызывает `topstr` и теряет выделенную память.
3. `gluestr` вызывает `realloc` на указателе `top` который указывает на буфер в стеке, а не на объект в куче. Это ломает всю свободную память и затирает стек.
4. `strcat` добавляет новые символы в буфер на стеке, а не в новой памяти. Хотя после предыдущего пункта это уже не важно.

### Как поправить

В `topstr` добавить копирование строки:

```
char *topstr(const char *s) {
    char *s2 = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    if (s2 == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed: insufficient memory\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(s2, s);
    return s2;
}
```

`gluestr` придётся капитально переписать. Теперь она возвращает флаг что строки склеены успешно. Если памяти хватило, то указатель `s1` может быть обновлен. Никогда не пишите `p = realloc(p, ...)` - в случае ошибки вы теряете указатель на старую память:

```
bool gluestr(char **s1, const char *s2) {
    size_t len1 = strlen(*s1);
    size_t len2 = strlen(s2);

    char *s3 = realloc(*s1, len1 + len2 + 1);
    if (s3 == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "realloc() failed: insufficient memory\n");
        return false;
    }
    strcat(s3, s2);
    *s1 = s3;
    return true;
}
```

Пример использования:

```
int main() {
    char str1[20];
    char str2[20];
    puts("Type a string");
    fgets(str1, sizeof(str1), stdin);
    fgets(str2, sizeof(str2), stdin);

    char *s = topstr(str1);
    if (s != NULL && gluestr(&s, str2)) {
        puts(s);
    }
}
```

### Бонус

`topstr` не нужна, если доработать `gluestr`. Добавим возможность обрабатывать нулевой указатель в `gluestr`. Изменится первая строчка: если `*s1 == NULL` то нельзя вызывать `strlen`. В конце функции `strcat(s3` заменён на `strcpy(s3 + len1`. Это нужно, так как `strcat` нельзя вызывать если в `s3` неинициализированная память:

```
bool gluestr(char **s1, const char *s2) {
    size_t len1 = (*s1 == NULL) ? 0 : strlen(*s1);
    size_t len2 = strlen(s2);

    char *s3 = realloc(*s1, len1 + len2 + 1);
    if (s3 == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "realloc() failed: insufficient memory\n");
        return false;
    }
    strcpy(s3 + len1, s2);
    *s1 = s3;
    return true;
}
```

Тогда пользоваться ею можно так:

```
char *s = NULL;
if (gluestr(&s, str1) && gluestr(&s, str2)) {
    puts(s);
}
```

`realloc` сам выделит память под первую строку если ему дать нулевой указатель.

Answer (score 2):

Компилируйте как С, а не как С++. Установите соответствующие настройки проекта или ключи командной строки.

Или добавьте приведение типа `(char*)`, как вы это делали с `malloc`:

```
top = (char*)realloc(top, sizeof(char)*(len1+len2+1));
```

Comment: `p = realloc(p)` - так нельзя.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Я отвечал на единственный вопрос - почему не компилируется код :)

Comment: Гм. Слона-то я и не приметил.